# Using Assumption with LaplaceInverseTransform

Tags: assumptions

I want to compute the the Laplace inverse transform of the following

$$\bar f(s)=\frac{1}{s^2+a s+b}$$

which clearly depends on $a^2-4b$. When I use Mathematica, it just gives the answer for the case $a^2-4b>0$. I couldn't resolve the issue by using `Assuming` or `Assumptions`. I mean how can I get the answer for the cases $a^2-4b=0$ and $a^2-4b<0$.

```
$Assumptions = {a^2 - 4 b == 0};
f = 1/(s^2 + a s + b);
InverseLaplaceTransform[f, s, t]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f = 1/(s^2 + a s + b);
inv = InverseLaplaceTransform[f, s, t]
```

[image]

```
FullSimplify[inv, a^2 - 4 b > 0]
```

[image]

```
FullSimplify[inv, a^2 - 4 b < 0]
```

[image]

assumming a and b are `Reals`:

```
FullSimplify[ComplexExpand@inv, a^2 - 4 b < 0]
```

[image]

```
Limit[inv, b -> a^2/4]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the attention. The result for $a^2-4b<0$ is incorrect! :) Indeed, what you have obtained for $a^2-4b>0$ and $a^2-4b<0$ is the same

Comment: @H.R. - The result for `a^2 - 4b < 0` is correct, it merely involves a complex argument to `Sinh`. If you want an explicitly real form, use `Assuming[a^2 - 4 b < 0, 
 inv // ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // 
  FullSimplify]` which evaluates to `(2*Sin[(1/2)*Sqrt[-a^2 + 4*b]*t])/
   (E^((a*t)/2)*Sqrt[-a^2 + 4*b])`

Comment: @H.R. The result is correct, o.k., for `Reals`do this `FullSimplify[ComplexExpand@inv, a^2 - 4 b < 0]`

Comment: Please add your last comment to the answer so that I can accept it. :)